# customize menu bar wordpress to build one page functionality

Tags: wordpress, menu, anchor

One part in my main menu (primary) should show submenus which links to different sections within a static site. So for example I have the main menu point "About us". When clicked the **dropdown** contains: "Team", "Resposibility", "Jobs"…

**But All these subpoints in the dropdown should not link to different sites, but to different sections within the one site "About us".**

It's **like a one page functionality** within a WP-Theme. But I need to customize this functionality.

**I have no idea how to set up this in the menu section.** (Because I am not dealing with different sites.)

I can imagine, that I could use a single page template and add `id` to the `h2` tags - as anchors to link to from the main menu. **But I don't know, how to register this and how to set up this in the menu bar.**

(My template does not offer one page functionality. *I just want this functionality only for one menu section.*)